# Navigationbar Translucent property

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

[image: FirstViewController navbar]

[image: Getting Spot in between]

[image: SecondViewController navbar is translucent]

I am having a requirement where my first view controller has

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

and second view controller has

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

so while navigating from first view controller to second view controller i can see a white space on top... can anyone help me for smooth navigation.

Answer (score 0):

try to insert following code into your viewDidLoad:

```
if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)] ) {
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: Had tried but not working for me please look at the images i've uploaded.

Comment: Have tried adding to both one by one none of them works jurk is still there